# Flex Embedding Roboto Font - Transcoding error?

Tags: css, apache-flex

I've spent hours on this and it makes no sense to me. I'm really hoping someone can help me out.

The code below will not compile because I
get:

```
-unable to build font 'robotoRegularNoCFF'
-Unable to transcode C:/Users/LAPTOP-PAT/git/application-mobile/ProInspector/src/assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf.
-exception during transcoding:`
```

The font embedded as CFF works fine - no issues at all. With embedded-as-cff:false, it won't compile.
The transcoding works fine with the SegoeUI font I downloaded, which is strange. All I need to do is replace the url, with the Segoe one and it works.

Also, If I leave out the embedded-as-cff:false, it compiles but I get the Serif font.

And if I set the primary font manager to flash.fonts.CFFFontManager (this is the default), this is what happens. BUT if I change the order and make the AFEFontManager the primary and CFFFontManager the secondary, it compiles and the MX components work great, but the spark components, which require CFF embedding, don't work!

Following is my code

```
/* Embed ROBOTO-Regular font */
/*Label, regular, w/ CFF */
@font-face {
    src: url("assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"); 
    fontFamily: "robotoRegular"; 
    embed-as-cff:true;
} 

/*Label, bold, w/ CFF */
@font-face { 
    src: url("assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"); 
    fontFamily: "robotoRegular";
    fontWeight: bold;
    embed-as-cff:true;
}

/*Label, regular, w/o CFF */
//**ERROR HERE**
@font-face { 
    src: url("assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"); 
    fontFamily: "robotoRegularNoCFF";
    embed-as-cff:false;
} 

/*Label, bold, w/o CFF */
//**ERROR HERE**
@font-face {
    src: url("assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"); 
    fontFamily: "robotoRegularNoCFF";
    fontWeight: bold;
    embed-as-cff:false;
}
```

Comment: So I found a solution: I converted to .otf from .ttf and it works fine now. still be curious as to why it wouldn't work, but it works now, which is all that matters.